# android custom listview very slow when scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, performance, android-listview

guys I got a problem with my listview. It runs so slow when scrolling can anybody help me. 
My listview is custom layout using relative with 3 textview and 1 imageview each row with all content is retrieve from the web. 
I use a custom adapter and a view holder.

below is my codes on how I use the adapter.

```
public class MessageList extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.listarticle);

        loadFeed(link);
        setListAdapter(new IconAdapter(this));

    }

 /* This method load xml file and parse it into message object*/
 private void loadFeed(String link){
     try{
      BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser(link);
      messages = parser.parse();
      titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
      image = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
      date_post = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
      descs = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
      for (Message msg : messages){
       titles.add(msg.getTitle());
       image.add(msg.getImageLink().toString());
       date_post.add(msg.getDate());
       descs.add(msg.getDescription());

      }
       } catch (Throwable t){
      Log.e("AndroidNews",t.getMessage(),t);
     }
    }

 /*this is my custom baseadapter */
 class IconAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
  private LayoutInflater mInflater;


  public IconAdapter(Context cxt){
   mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(cxt);


  }

  public class ViewHolder{
   private TextView title;
   private TextView date;
   private TextView desc;
   private ImageView thumb;
  }

  public View getView(int positiion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
   ViewHolder holder;

   if (convertView==null){
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    holder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deskripsi);
    holder.thumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
   }else{

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   holder.title.setText(titles.get(positiion));
   holder.date.setText(date_post.get(positiion));
   holder.desc.setText(descs.get(positiion).substring(0, 55)+"...");
   Drawable draw = LoadImageFromWebOperation(image.get(positiion));

   holder.thumb.setImageDrawable(draw);

   return convertView;
  }
  /* this method take image from url that retrieve from xml*/
  public Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperation(String url){
   try{
    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
    return d;
   }catch (Exception e){
    Log.d("image", url, e);
    return null;
   }
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return messages.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
   return messages.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
  }

 }
```

Comment: Edit and format the code in your question to better understand your problem.

Comment: thx. i've remove some code. hope you can understand the problem

Comment: @Raha, in your constructor, Make all your URL requests and store them in an array, in the `getView` don't load them again...that'll speed it up.

Comment: @st0le, thx for your comment. but i already store them to array at loadFeed method. and i didn't load them on get view.

Comment: @Raha, no dude, you're storing just the URL...I'm asking you to store the `Drawable` Object itself...geez! While scrolling you're `getView` will make repeated web requests...

Comment: ow i got it. so i should use a list of drawable to hold it first then put them on the adapter?

Comment: @st0le dude thats really makes my list faster when scrolling. thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @Raha, No problem. I'll post it as an answer, just in case...

Answer (score 12):

```
  public View getView(int positiion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
      ...
      Drawable draw = LoadImageFromWebOperation(image.get(positiion));
      ...
  }
```

This is the problem. You should never ever do networking in UI thread. Implement some async task for the job. 
Also, you can use traceview http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html tool to determine performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 4):

This is your problem, right here..

```
Drawable draw = LoadImageFromWebOperation(image.get(positiion));
```

Instead of making repeated URL Requests in your `getView()`, Make all your requests at once and store the `Drawables` in an array, and then use the array inside the `getView`. This will make it considerably faster...

Comment: yup. i've done that and it works perfectly. thx for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the link in this answer: [Scrolling large lists of Cursor-based adapters is faster than much smaller lists of in-memory adapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084967/scrolling-large-lists-of-cursor-based-adapters-is-faster-than-much-smaller-lists)

Comment: thx for share, but i already use viewholder and reuse the convertview

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use View Holder pattern in getview.

ViewHolder holder = null;

String fileName = arrfiles.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.unsubmited_row, parent,
                    false);
            convertView.setClickable(false);
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtFileName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtFileName);
        holder.txtisActive = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtIsActive);
        holder.txtFileName.setText(fileName);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
```